# What are the REST APIs available for Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I came across 2 links about the REST APIs for Kafka Connect. There are some additional ones in https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#connect . Get a 404 error when I use `GET /connectors/{name}/status` or `POST /connectors/{name}/restart` . But these services aren't listed on http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/userguide.html#rest-interface .

How do we check if the connector is running correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your link to the Apache website Kafka Connect documentation is indeed the most recent one (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation)

But your link to Kafka Connect documentation in Confluent's website refers to an older version of Confluent platform. You may always access the most recent version of Confluent Platform docs here:

http://docs.confluent.io

Comment: Thank you for letting me know Konstantine. The https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#connect lists REST services like restart, status, resume, pause . But I get a 404 error when I try these. The other services like listing connectors, tasks etc work fine. Not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: I have confluent 2.0.0 version installed.

Comment: In this case, the version that you have (confluent platform 2.0.0) is not in agreement with the docs you are reading from Apache.

The docs that would align the most with the version you are using are under Kafka 0.9.0 documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html). That is besides the docs for Confluent platform 2.0.0. (You'll have to scroll/search to reach Connect section because clicking on the sidebar takes you to the most recent version).

As you can see there, the status endpoint for instance is not listed in Apache Kafka either.

Comment: Got it! I'm using confluent-3.0.0 now. My connector config looks like:
`{"name":"hdfs-sink-connector","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector","tasks.max":"10","topics":"test-topic","hdfs.url":"hdfs://fakehost:9000","hadoop.conf.dir":"/opt/hadoop/conf","hadoop.home":"/opt/hadoop","flush.size":"100","rotate.interval.ms":"1000","name":"hdfs-sink-connector"},"tasks":[]}` . I also get 201 response code but <see_next_comment>

Comment: but I get this error: `ERROR Found connector configuration (connector-hdfs-sink-connector) in wrong format: class org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore:498)` . And the new connector will not be listed in the list of connectors. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I fixed this. I had an error in the worker configuration file.

Comment: Hello Konstantine! I see that you work for Confluent so I had another question. Once the connector writes files to HDFS, how will the downstream applications consuming from HDFS know that data is available? Is there some kind of notification handled by connector?

Comment: There's no such notification mechanism in the current hdfs connector. The downstream app should keep track of HDFS contents itself. If integration with Hive is used, Hive picks up the data immediately.

Comment: Just allow me to suggest that if you have additional, new questions you might want to submit them as separate questions in SO. Keeping the discussion going in the comments section seems hard. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I'll submit a new question with additional questions. Thanks, again!

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. I got "ERROR Found connector configuration in wrong format: class org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct" and REST APIs are not listing my connectors. How did you solve this? Please help.